# awk: –f awk: ^ invalid char '�' in expression

Tags: awk, gawk

Hi I have the following awk program

Problem is that I don't know why it complains **"awk: –f
awk: ^ invalid char '�' in expression"** when I do **awk -f pdf.awk aodv1.tr**

Anyone of you out there who are brighter than me in this area? =)

```
BEGIN {
   recvdSize = 0
   startTime = 400
   stopTime = 0
}

{
         event = $1
         time = $265.01
         node_id = $29
         pkt_size = $8
         level = $4



if (level == "AGT" && event == "s" && pkt_size >= 512) {
if (time < startTime) {
         startTime = time
         }
   }


  if (level == "AGT" && event == "r" && pkt_size >= 512) {
   if (time > stopTime) {
         stopTime = time
         }



   hdr_size = pkt_size % 512
   pkt_size -= hdr_size


   recvdSize += pkt_size
   }
   }

  END {
   printf("Average Throughput[kbps] = %.2f\t\t StartTime=%.2f\tStopTime=%.2f\n",(recvdSize/(stopTime-startTime))*(8/1000),startTime,stopTime)
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Didn't the error message tell you a line number? Anyway, I'd take a close look at the line that contains

```
time = $265.01
```

if I were you!